# Laravel 7 Kernel classes issue with session

Tags: laravel, session-cookies

i have a issue with my code.I have user these classes in my Kernel file in laravel

```
protected $middleware = [
    // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \Spatie\CookieConsent\CookieConsentMiddleware::class,
];
```

And my Controller code is

```
        if($category->save()){
            return redirect()->route('category.index')->with('done','Category has been inserted successfully');
        }else{
            return back()->with('deny','Something went wrong');
        }
```

My view code is

```
    @if (session('deny'))
    <div class="alert bg-danger text-white alert-styled-left alert-dismissible">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>×</span></button>
        <span class="font-weight-semibold">Oh snap!</span> {{ session('deny') }}.
    </div>
@endif

@if (session('done'))
    <div class="alert bg-success text-white alert-styled-left alert-dismissible">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>×</span></button>
        <span class="font-weight-semibold">Well done!</span> {{ session('done') }}.
    </div>
@endif
```

my issue is my message is not displaying  after i removed my classes from Kernel file then my message is display.
How to fixed this without removing classes from Kernel

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class
```

Answer (score 0):

When you disable laravel from using php sessions by disabling StartSession::class
you can not access session variables, because there is non.

If this is not what you have meant to ask, I have to tell you, that I don't understand your question at all

Comment: i just used StartSession::class in kernel for get user()->name in error pages like 404 page

Comment: it's worked but my session message is not working